# Autotools doesn't like the install.sh script in my project directory

Tags: c++, build, makefile, installation, autotools

I have an autotools project with the following project structure:

```
|-- Makefile.am
|-- configure.ac
|-- config.guess
|-- build
|-- include
|   `-- code
|       |-- File.h
|-- libCode
|   |-- File.cpp
|   |-- Makefile.am
`-- install.sh
```

When I build the project, I run into this error:

```
BUG.am: `install.sh' is an anachronism; use `install-sh' instead
```

I tried to get around that problem by adding the following to configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build])
```

which in turn gives me this error:

```
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ../../config.sub
```

Note: I cannot rename install.sh due to several dependency changes. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Your `install.sh` script matches the name of an autotools-provider script, no matter what you use it for. Since most of those scripts are identified by name rather than content, I'd be surprised if this is the only bug it triggers.

As for the failure when providing `AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR`, have you executed `autoreconf -fis` after changing that? Which directory are you trying to build into? If you are using `build` to run `../configure` in, that won't work.